# Why I can't I telnet to a specific port?

Tags: networking, server, connection, telnet

the port 7778 is in listen,

```
netstat -tulpn
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:7778   0.0.0.0:*        LISTEN      22776/java
```

but I can't telnet that port from remote machine while I can telnet other port by using this command

```
telnet 192.168.1.100 port_number
```

Comment: What do you mean "remote machine"? A machine outside your LAN, or a machine in your LAN?

Comment: I mean in the same LAN

Comment: I am pretty sure its because you are only listening on ip address  127.0.0.1 so only on loopback. You cant connect to that from anywhere.

Comment: You said you couldn't "telnet that port" (7778) from the other machine, but what follows that suggests that you could do that. Could you explain what you're doing that doesn't work?

Comment: i edit my question, i meant that i can telnet other ports from remote machine

Comment: this looks like a XY problem, was java runtime meant to be use from external hosts ? is yes, you should configure it.

Comment: yes it will be used from external hosts, this was my question in comment bellow, how to configure java to listen on IP address instead of localhost to be able to use it from remote machines.

Comment: Please refrain from asking any [X-Y question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @heemayl : first time heard about XY question, because i still new here

Answer (score 2):

The address `127.0.0.1` is the loopback address.

As you have the `127.0.0.1:7788` in the "Local Address" of `netstat` output, this means that the connection is only listening for connections originating from this computer only on the loopback interface. No other computers on the network can reach your loopback address directly hence the `telnet` is failing from other computers.

Comment: yes I can only telnet that port from localhost but i can't telnet it from remote host, so howto change it? i mean to use the address it instead of localhost and make it accessible by other machines?

Answer (score 2):

java is listening in `127.0.0.1`, that is localhost.

You can't connect from outside, unless you do some kind of forwarding, using ssh for instance.

Edit:

from external hosts,

if unix/linux

```
ssh -L 1234:127.0.0.1:7778 runtime
```

- then from that external host, `telnet 127.0.0.1 1234`
  (ssh will forward you)

if windows, use putty or bitwise to forward local port 1234 to 7778 on host holding runtime.

Comment: there is no way to force java to listen in IP address?

Comment: You can alway rewrite the part of code that listen(), then recompile. Or ask your Oracle support.